# Assuming a monotonic function

Tags: equation-solving, assumptions

I'm trying to tell Mathematica that a function is increasing. More specifically, I would like at least one of the following statements to report 'true'.

```
$Assumptions = a > b && ForAll[{a, b}, Implies[a > b, f[a] > f[b]]]
FullSimplify[f[a] > f[b] && $Assumptions]
Reduce[f[a] > f[b] && $Assumptions]
Resolve[f[a] > f[b] && $Assumptions]
Refine[f[a] > f[b] && $Assumptions]
```

At best Mathematica just reports back that 'f[a] > f[b]', which to me implies its not understanding either than a>b or that f[a]>f[b].

I don't know if I am providing the wrong assumptions, using assumptions incorrectly, or using the the wrong evaluation technique. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Up to the documentation, neither `ForAll` nor `Exists` deal with abstract functions (functional terms).

Comment: Thanks. Does that basically mean Mathematica can't do this?

Comment: You may create a Mathematica package to this end on your own.

Comment: Can you point me to the documentation? I'm not exactly sure what the restriction is since this seems to work:
`proof = FindEquationalProof[ForAll[x, f[f[x]] == g[g[x]]], 
  ForAll[x, f[x] == g[x]]]`

Comment: The above is another cup of tea. If you  look in [FindEquationalProof](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindEquationalProof.html), you will see that command does not work wit `+` and `<`. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: Did you try writing the function as the integral of its primitive, then assume the primitive to be $>0$ ?